# Custom form for uploading documents

Tags: 2013, custom-form, edit

I would like to add some text above the Drop Down Box for the Content Type selection box. I am assuming that I will need to create a new Edit Form and or `uploadform.aspx` in SP designer?

How do I do this and where do I place the code?

[image]

Comment: The easiest option will be to use JavaScript to add the text.

Comment: OK thanks. Any suggests on how I do that :-) Javascript novice here

Comment: Do you use jQuery in your site?

Comment: Yes I believe we do

Comment: @Mike: Just a thought..If you want just a generic label for that Content Type, try adding description for your content types in the content type settings and I believe the new form will show the description there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open SharePoint Designer 2013, and select the Open Site menu:
Type the site name into the Open Site dialog box, and click the Open button.

Go to the Lists and Libraries tab, and select any list that needs to be modified:
Go to the Forms section. You will see three default forms including:

DispForm.aspx: Display item form
EditForm.aspx: Edit item form
NewForm.aspx: New item form

Click on the New button at the top-right of the Forms section.  A Create New List Form window will appear:

In the File Name textbox, type the form name that you want to use.
Under the Select the type of form to create section, select the type of form you want to create.
New item form: used to add new items to the list
Edit item form: used to edit existing list items
Display item form: used to view list items
Check on the Set as default form the selected type if you want
Click the OK button.

The new form will be shown in the Forms section:

Click on the New Form to modify:

There is default look you can check by clicking HOME tab / Preview in Browser

But as you can see there is some extra material, so lets begin.
To add text,let as first locate input field in code, and above it add
 Some text...
[image]

Now you have text you wanted, all you need to do now is delete extra save/cancel buttons and rest fields you dont need.[image]

Locate those in code and delete.
[image]
[image]

Now you have it. :)

[image]

Comment: Link only answers are not very useful because links tend to break over time. Consider adding more of a detailed explanation to your answer.

Comment: I have edited the form directly in SP desisgner rather than use a script.  My new problem now is that the text appears above the yellow information box.  Can I force this to appear until the box?

Comment: Thing is, you need to find part of code which you wish to edit, my advice to you is, paste
<label>position 1...</label>......
on multiple places in code to find one that suits to you.
Until you get it where you want.
If you have succeeded to place text already you are on right track.

Answer (score 1):

Open the edit form page in browser and then add a Script Editor Webpart. Edit the Snippet and use below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var textToAppend = "<b>Text to Insert</b><br/>";
        var temp = $('select[Title="Content Type"]').parent().html();
        $('select[Title="Content Type"]').parent().html(textToAppend + temp);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Great thanks, one more question.  Is it OK to paste this code anywhere in the form?

Comment: @MikeBlair Yes. Make sure you are adding a Script Editor Webpart and not Content Editor.